# read file line by line and remember the last position in file

Tags: files, read

I want to grep some line from a log file with an input from another file. I'm using this small command to do that:

```
while read line; do 
    grep "$line" service.log; 
done < input_strings.txt > result.txt
```

`input_strings.txt` has like 50 000 strings (one per line). For every of this string I'm currently searching the huge `service.log` file (with around 2 000 000 lines).

So lets say the 1st string of `input_strings.txt` is found in `service.log` at line 10 000, this line gets written to my `result.txt`. After that, the 2nd string of `input_strings.txt` will be searched in `service.log`, BUT starting at line 1 of `service.log`.

How can I remember the last line I found the 1st entry in `service.log`? So that I can start the 2nd search-run there?

Comment: I should realize that relying on the last match position/offset will not give you all possible matches from `input_strings.txt`

Comment: In this case it would. Because i got the right order in both files. i am sure, that the 2nd string from input_strings.txt is NOT before the 1st match.

Comment: you are contradicting yourself: at first time you said *the 2nd string of input_strings.txt will be searched in service.log, BUT starting at line 1 of service.log* - then, you added *i am sure, that the 2nd string from input_strings.txt is NOT before the 1st match*. Absolutely contradictory

Comment: Yes, thats the current status of my problem. _italic_the 2nd string of input_strings.txt will be searched in service.log, BUT starting at line 1 of service.log_italic_ << thats the problem of my while read line; to grep....

I just want to get the last position of a matched line, so i can start at this point for the next run of my while loop.

Comment: @xMaNuu I think that the approach that you're taking here to solve the problem seems suboptimal and it seems to me that you're likely to get a lot of resistance unless you give a clear explanation for why you want to go about things this way, e.g. why use a loop at all?

Comment: @igal, well, this would be a good opportunity to show them a better way of doing that, instead of using the shell, right? I don't think `grep` by itself can look for matches in a particular order.

Comment: @ilkkachu It's not clear to me exactly what they're asking for.

Comment: @xMaNuu You might also want to add small example files to demonstrate the desired output for some given input.

Comment: @xMaNuu, About using shell loops to process text, see: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/170373). In brief: it's slow, and there are some gotchas, like the fact that you probably want to use `read -r` instead of plain `read` approximately every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the matches then you don't need to be using a loop at all. It would be much faster to just use a single `grep` command:

```bsh
grep -Ff input_strings service.log > results.txt
```

That said, if you want to do literally what you stated in your question, then you could use a variable to keep track of the line on which the last match was found:

```bsh
LINE_NUMBER=0
while read LINE; do

    # Search for the next match starting at the line number of the previous match
    MATCH="$(tail -n+${LINE_NUMBER} "service.log" | grep -n "${LINE}" | head -n1)";

    # Extract the line number from the match result
    LINE_NUMBER="${MATCH/:*/}";

    # Extract the matching string from the match result
    STRING="${x#*:}";

    # Output the matching string
    echo "${STRING}";

done < input_strings.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: grep -Ff input_strings service.log > results.txt

Thats exactly what i was looking for! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I gather you want to search for the first keyword, then continue on the line after that match to search for the next keyword etc., printing the matches as you go.

Given `keywords`:

```
foo
bar
```

And `data`:

```
bar 0
foo 1
bar 1
foo 2
```

The `awk` script here should do just that (tested with GNU awk):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {i = j = 0} NR==FNR { k[i++] = $0; next} 
       $0 ~ k[j] {j++; print $0} j >= i {exit}' keywords data 
foo 1
bar 1
```

`i` and `j` start at 0, and during the first file (`NR==FNR` compares the record/line number of the current file to total number of lines seen), we collect the keywords to an array. After that, try to match the `j`:th keyword, and print and increase `j` on a match. Exit after all keywords are found.

As with `grep`, the keywords here are actually regex patterns, though obviously `awk` regexes here. If you want to search for fixed strings, use `index($0, key)` instead of `$0 ~ key`.

---

Alternatively, without loading the keywords at the start:

```
$ awk -vkeyfile=keywords 'BEGIN {getline key < keyfile } 
      $0 ~ key {print $0; if (!getline key < keyfile) exit;}' data
foo 1 
bar 1
```

This should be straightforward.